# Debug helm look up for secret.yml

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, minikube

I have a secret.yml file , and run `helm install test5 ./ -n mynamespace`. When opened in k8 dashboard secret, i am able to see the secret value.

below code is from deployment.yml file

```
{{- $secret := default (dict "data" (dict)) (lookup "v1" "Secret" .Release.Namespace  "mysecrets") }}
{{- if $secret.data.redispassword }}
  {{- $redisPassword := $secret.data.redispassword | b64dec }}
{{- end }}
```

When installs, above condition is not met, even if value is present

Below code works,

```
valueFrom:
secretKeyRef:
name: mysecrets
key: redispassword
```

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ljn6.jpg)

I need to get password in template for multiple condition purpose

helm dry-run prints the secrct.yml file. The issue is with lookup, How to print all value of a screct.yml to debug. Something like covert dictionary object to string.

Thank you for your consideration, help and time.
Repo link - https://github.com/DevSecOpsTut/helm-test